# Log out issue in IIS Hosted sites with different port numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, logout

**Issue:**  I have two websites hosted in IIS like below

MySiteName1:8017
MySiteName2:8020

when I log in to one website (ex : MySiteName1:8017 ) its working perfect.
when I try to log in to another website(ex: MySiteName2:8020) in the same browser
previously opened website(ex : MySiteName1:8017 ) is going to log out automatically.

and I use forms authentication

**How to stop this automatic logout**

Comment: have you somehow designed it so they share a session? It's very hard to know anything with such a minimal description of your environment.

Comment: @ADyson am not sure about sharing session for both websites where we can check that setup?. if you want to review any code block or set up details from my end  Please let me know. I will share them here